# Trying to get results from a query in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, select

I am trying to retrieve values from multiple rows. Like in php you do with odbc_fetch_row and obdc_result. That's because I want to print a receipt with the values from 2 tables but I don't know what I should do.
Here is the query:

```
string query="SELECT * FROM faturas_online_detalhe WHERE cod_fatura='"+codfatura+"';";
```

Edit, added the code I already had so far:

```
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand comando2 = new OleDbCommand();
        comando2.Connection = connection;
        comando2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM detalhe_faturas_online WHERE cod_fatura = '" + codfatura + "'; ";
        OleDbDataReader reader = comando2.ExecuteReader();
        string outValues = string.Empty;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            outValues += string.Format("Column 1 = {0}, Column 2 = {1}, etc...", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outValues);
        lst1.Items.Add(outValues);
        connection.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

Edit here is an image of how the database is looking like:
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Please include any other related code so we can at least see how far along you are. You should be using a connection object, command object, etc... Something like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` or a derivative. You should also use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation.

Comment: most import thing is to first establish a connection to your Data source.
If you are using some sort of ORM framework or direct DB connection the process will be a little different

Comment: edited out so ill show you the code

Comment: You should be using `ExecuteReader`, you can then use the reader to access your data.

Comment: I dont know why but it his allready working , now i only got to isolate that ,thank you , +1!

Comment: Just a question , i am trying to get preco value , and it seems that because it is currency it isnt letting me get the value to string , what should i do?

Comment: You should take a look at the `OleDbDataReader` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - You can use `GetDouble` function. The `GetString` function does not do implicit conversion of underlying datatypes. The `GetString` in my example, was only just for that, an example. You will need to use the appropriate function that pertains to the underlying datatype of your columns. Which is one of the reasons you should specify your columns in your select list. It will make things clearer and help prevent future issues if anything changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to likely use `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteScalar`. You will use the reader to access the table data returned by your query. I would also suggest using parameterized queries instead of string concatenation:

```
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand();
    comando.Connection = connection;
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM faturas_online_detalhe WHERE cod_fatura= @parm1;";
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", codfatura);
    OleDbReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader() ;
    string outValues = string.Empty;
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        outValues += string.Format("Column 1 = {0}, Column 2 = {1}, etc...", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(outValues);
    txtOutput.Text = outValues;
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Im working around your code to make it work in my program , thank you so much again ! +1

Comment: But i just found out , it doesnt work when there are more than one record in the receipt details

Comment: How do you mean? This code will loop through each record returned from the query and print the contents.

Comment: When i do console writeline it doesnt even show anything

Comment: Are you certain there is data for the query you are executing? Also, it would help to know what your table structure is, and what some sample data would be. If you set a break-point in the code and check that the value in `codfatura` is valid, then perform the select statement using that value, do you get any data? It would also be better to specify your return columns instead of using `SELECT *`.

Comment: For example ,the first column wich has a code of FO59 and a product code oh cha1 ,quantity of 1 and price of 1 and total of 1, there is one other FO59 with another product code and quantity and price and total. The receipts like FO59( that have more than 1 products to it) are not showing in my textbox but the receipts with one product are.And the writeline isnt even showing me  anything

Comment: and codfatura is allways with a variable in it

Comment: What is the textbox that you are referring to? Does the textbox contain the output from this query, or does it contain the ID that you are passing in to `codfatura`? You should edit your question to contain more of your code, specifically your input and output controls, along with a sample structure of your table and some data. The code in my answer should write to your console so long as there are records that match the value passed in.

Comment: The textbox im referring to is just one textbox i have so i can output values to it when i want o confirm something.i used it to contain the result , and it only had the ones with one product of the receipt, and i tried with listbox and it only also gives me the results of the receipts who has only 1 product

Comment: Also, I am not certain what you mean by `codfatura is always with a variable in it`... `codfatura` is a variable, what assigns a value to it? Is the value being assigned to it a value that exists in your table? If the value assigned to that variable does not exist in the table, no records will be returned and no data will write to the console.

Comment: If you are writing the output from the `while` loop, you will need to concatenate the values together within the while loop. I will modify the answer a bit... You would also likely want to ensure the textbox is set to allow multiline.

Comment: It still doesnt work , it still only show the receipts that have only 1

Comment: "Receipt code" doesn't really mean anything to me. Like I said, it would be a big help if you modified your question to include more of the information I asked about, specifically the table structure: column names, datatypes, and some sample data. Aside from that information, expanding upon your c# code in your question to include how you are setting your variable for the input, and how you are setting the output values going into your textbox. Without that stuff a lot of what I provide is really guess-work. The code I provided is very basic, and works. I dont know how youre trying to use it.

Comment: added a screenshot with the database

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Set a breakpoint and step through execution a line at a time? Check your values during execution to ensure everything is correct. Check the contents of `codfatura` during execution, and check the contents of `outValues` after the loop.

Comment: Also, the name of your table in the image is different than the name in the select statement you provided: `faturas_online_detalhe` versus `detalhe_faturas_online`.

Comment: after debugging i can start to think a bit better about resolving this , but i gotta go to sleep now, if i need anything more ill place a comment here, thank you for your help

Comment: i modified it on the program since the beggining

Answer (score 0):

`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

You probably want something like `ExecuteQuery()` or `ExecuteReader()` instead. Note that this was found simply by Googling "ExecuteScalar" - it was the first result. Don't be afraid to Google your code!

Comment: Thank you , i will! i searched thing as the title , not the code itself, but i still cant figure out how to get the values from the query, i can do it with 1 column , not multiple